# Concatenation of several hdf5 having a dimension common to two groups

Tags: h5py, nco

I would like to concatenate several hdf5 files.
Here is the header given with panoply :

[image: Here is the header given with panoply]

I'd like to concatenate on the npixels dimension.
But if I do a ncrcat on npixels it tells me 'variable unknown'.
Indeed if I do a `ncdump -c`, I don't see the `npixels` dimension but phony_dim_0 in the `Data_Fields` group and phony_dim_4 in the `Geolocation_Fields`, each with 655 pixels.

I put these dimensions unlimited with :

```
ncks --mk_rec_dmn phony_dim_0 ${file} ${file}
ncks -O --mk_rec_dmn phony_dim_4 ${file} ${file}
```

If I do :

```
ncrcat Valid_CO_SOFRID-v4.0_200???.he5 Valid_CO_SOFRID-v4.0_200801-200907.he5 -v Latitude,Longitude,Day,Hour,Minute,"CO Total Column"
```

(with only 1D variables), it seems to work for the `Geolocation_Fields` variables. For the `Data_Fields` variables I get the expected number of element but with the same value (probably an average).
Same output if I keep only 1 variable:

```
ncrcat -d phony_dim_0,0, Valid_CO_SOFRID-v4.0_200???.he5 Valid_CO_SOFRID-v4.0_200801-200907_dim0.he5 -v "CO Total Column"
```

Actually I also need to take an additional variable which is 2D but it does not work:

```
ERROR: nco_put_vara() failed to nc_put_vara() variable "CO"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Short NCO-generated message (usually name of function that triggered error): nco_put_vara()
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Error code is -40. Translation into English with nc_strerror(-40) is "NetCDF: Index exceeds dimension bound"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded it with h5py \o/

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import glob
import collections
import os

def nested_dict():
    return collections.defaultdict(nested_dict)

path = '/home/loip/Documents/tech/sofrid/data/windhoekSameDayOnly/'
listOfAllFiles = glob.glob( path + 'Valid_CO_SOFRID-v2.2_200???.he5' )

os.chdir( path )

dico = nested_dict()
with h5py.File('Valid_CO_SOFRID-v2.2_200801-200907.he5', 'w') as h5w:
    for iFile, eachFile in enumerate(listOfAllFiles):   
        with h5py.File(eachFile, 'r') as h5r:
            for group in ['HDFEOS']:
                for subgroup1 in ['SWATHS']:
                    for subgroup2 in ['CO']:
                        for subgroup3 in h5r[group][subgroup1][subgroup2].keys(): #Data Fields & Geolocation Fields
                            for varName in h5r[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3].keys():
                                dataThisTime = h5r[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName][:]
                                if iFile == 0:
                                    dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName] = dataThisTime
                                else:
                                    if dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName].ndim == 2:
                                        dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName] = np.append( dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName], dataThisTime, axis=1 )
                                    else:
                                        dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName] = np.append( dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName], dataThisTime, axis=0 )
                                if iFile == len(listOfAllFiles)-1:
                                    h5w.create_dataset(f'{group}/{subgroup1}/{subgroup2}/{subgroup3}/{varName}', 
                                                       data=dico[group][subgroup1][subgroup2][subgroup3][varName])
```